# Xslt: how to select xml elements by class selector in a xslt stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt

My html code (which is into an xslt file)

```
<p class=".hello">hello</p>
```

Why css class-selector is not working in my css ? (this css file is called by a xslt stylesheet).

My css code

```
.hello{
    color: red; /*not working */
}

p{
    color: red; /* working */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line

```
<p class="hello">hello</p>
```

to set a class accessible by

```
.hello { ... }
```

And this line to set an ID:

```
<p id="hello">hello</p>
```

accessible by

```
#hello { ... }
```

Summary: one dot too much in your `class` attribute value.